# Printing the physical address of a C pointer

Tags: c, memory

I can print the address of a pointer by using the following code

```
#include<stdio.
int main(){
    int *q =(int*) malloc(4);
    printf("%x\n",q);
}
```

When i execute the following code a hexadecimal value is printed. Is it the virtual address or the physical address of variable q on heap? If it is virtual how should i print the other?

Comment: It's always the virtual address, the physical address is hidden to you.

Comment: @ouah Is there a way to print the physical address?

Comment: @SanjeevSharma btw use `%p` instead of `%x` and type-cast address to `void*` as `printf("%p\n", (void*)q);`

Comment: Should be `int *q = malloc(sizeof *q);` while we're at it.

Comment: Some computers don't have virtual memory - in that case it is the physical address.  But if the OS uses virtual memory then it is a virtual address.  If it is a virtual address then only the OS knows where it is mapped.  Here is something that may help explain: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7HoguhFVQ4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's in terms of virtual address space. It's impossible to get a "physical" address in standard C (unless you're on a system which doesn't have virtual memory, of course, in which case it'll always be the physical address) - if it's currently in swap space, for instance, it may not even have one, other than a current location on disk, which wouldn't be very useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way of the program knowing whether it is a virtual or physical address. The memory is handled by the operating system and MMU which hands out addresses to the program.

Comment: It is the virtual address unless there isn't a virtual address space.